# QGIS: Update parent attribute based on most recent child

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression, relation

To describe the situation, I have parent geopackage layer for 'Trees' which is related to a child geopackage table 'tree_inspections'. So each tree can have many inspections. I use a foreign key 'tree_UUID' to link them.

How can i link attributes in the parent 'tree' layer to the most recent related entry in 'tree_inspections'?

For example the "height" attribute of a 'tree' is based on the input "height" of the most recent 'tree_inspection'.

Or a trickier example, the "next inspection due" date of a 'tree' is based on [date of the most recent inspection + X years] where X is also comes from a "reinspect in X years" integer field within 'tree_inspections'.